# I would like to fit a data to integral type model but cannot figure it how?

Tags: optimization, curve-fitting

I have cumulative data for concentration versus time. I would like to fit the following model to the data:

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(n) \bar{t}}\int_{0}^{\frac{n t}{\bar{t}}}z^{n-1}  e^{-z}dz$$

$n$ and $\bar{t}$ are the variables that I would like to fit. I tried to make a function with integral included but I wasn't successful would you please give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Your integral can explicitly be written in terms of Gamma functions as

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(n) \bar{t}}\int_{0}^{\frac{n t}{\bar{t}}}z^{n-1}  e^{-z}dz = \frac{1}{ \Gamma(n) \bar{t}}\gamma\left(n, \frac{n t}{\bar{t}}\right)\, .$$

Comment: @isar-charmchi Do you _really_ mean for the $n$ in the integration interval to be the same as the $n$ in $z^{n-1}$?

Comment: "I wasn't successful" is really not a very useful part of a question. Describe what you did, what happened, and how specifically it did not work.